# Ofbiz: Error on Set OFBIZ_HOME

Tags: ofbiz

I'm trying to compile the ofbiz in my local machine. I'm getting the follow error:

[image]

Any idea the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting OFBIZ_HOME works without an error. The problem occurs, as the following stacktrace shows, during the OFBiz start sequence. The specified port is already in use.

It is very likely that you already have started OFBiz before so that the port is occupied by this instance. Close all running OFBiz instances and the errors should be gone.

Comment: Please follow Michael's advice: the error is telling you that the port 10523 is already in use; this is the port from which OFBiz listens for admin commands.

Comment: Yes, it was that. Thank you